# net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist: Error reading configuration file

Tags: corda

I downloaded cordapp template (Java) from https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java.

Everytime I make chage to the project gradlew deplyNodes fails with below error. However, it automatically gets resolved once I restart my system.

Is there anything, I am missing?

```
> Configure project :
Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0
        at build_d668pifueefmtb65xfqnh374z$_run_closure5.doCall(C:\Users\amit.pamecha\Documents\workspace\abcdwork\capital-coin\cordapp-template-java\build.gradle:83)
The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
        at build_d668pifueefmtb65xfqnh374z$_run_closure5.doCall(C:\Users\amit.pamecha\Documents\workspace\abcdwork\capital-coin\cordapp-template-java\build.gradle:83)

> Task :deployNodes
Bootstrapping local network in C:\Users\amit.pamecha\Documents\workspace\abcdwork\capital-coin\cordapp-template-java\build\nodes
Node config files found in the root directory - generating node directories
Generating directory for Notary
Generating directory for PartyA
Generating directory for PartyB
Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [Notary, PartyA, PartyB]
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
Distributing all node info-files to all nodes
Gathering notary identities


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
> net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist: Error reading configuration file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
12 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 8 up-to-date
```

Comment: I am assuming network is not shutting down as cordapp\build\libs\cordapp-0.1.jar is not getting deleted when I try to clean/manually delete build folder. Is there any way to shutdown entire network/cordapp in one command?

Comment: If on windows try `taskkill /f /im java.exe`

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a stale Gradle process. You need to kill this process.

You can use `killall java -9` or `pkill java` on Unix, or `wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete`, to kill all Java processes.

Or you can use something like:

- `lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN` to find processes and ports
- `ps ax | grep <pid>` to confirm the command line of the process
- `kill -9 <pid>`